# Python 3.x XAMPP UTF-8 encoding

Tags: windows, python-3.x, apache, utf-8, xampp

I am making a small python driven web page. It works fine, but it is Windows-1250 encoded. If I put meta tag for UTF-8 encoding to support our special characters ČŠŽ I get question marks. 
If I put html code in simple .html document it shows fine. But in .py file it is not working OK.

```
print("content-type: text/html\n" )
print('<html>')
print('<head>')
print('<title>Python page</title>')
print('<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />')
print('</head>')
```

I checked httpd.conf and added

```
#UTF 8
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

but it does the same as meta tag.

Comment: Is your source file *saved* in UTF-8?

Comment: Yes. Checked with Notepad++ and PyCharm